# Does Arnold Schwarzenegger intentionally strengthen his accent in older movies?

Tags: character, dialogue, acting

There are plenty of soundboard apps with Arnold Schwarzenegger's famous movie quotes that make him sound really Austrian and sort of funny. Considering how much time he had spent in United States before his filming career began I suspect that his accent is slightly exaggerated in the movies.

Was this done intentioanally to give him some sort of well memorized character image?

Comment: My guess is that Arnold's accent gradually disappeared with time.

Comment: "How much time" was only two years, eight if you ignore when he was dubbed out.

Comment: Also, his accent is Austrian, not German.

Comment: Based on old interviews for his weight lifting days, no.

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

Because it's part of his [persona](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-3141778/Arnold-Schwarzenegger-reveals-speak-perfect-English-keeps-talking-accent-fans-expect-it.html).

Schwarzenegger says his fans expect it.

> He said that he could speak unaccented English ‘if I need to’ but added: ‘The very things that they said would make it impossible for me to be successful in acting were the things that became my assets,’ referring to his name, his voice and his physique.

Answer (score 2):

No, he did not fake his accent in the early movies.  His accent was so bad in 1969, they dubbed over his voice in 'Hercules in New York'.

Here you can see him in 2007, not acting, he still has an accent, but it is not as strong as it was before.  I would say this is his natural English.

He revealed in 2015 that he can speak without the Austrian accent if he wanted to, but chooses not to because people like him with the accent and expect it.  By the 80's was able to speak without the accent fairly well